# webrtc and peerjs: how to play a stream without starting his own stream?

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I am using peerjs

**Media call**

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {
  var call = peer.call('another-peers-id', stream);
  call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
    // Show stream in some video/canvas element.
  });
}, function(err) {
  console.log('Failed to get local stream' ,err);
});
```

**Answer**

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
peer.on('call', function(call) {
  getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {
    call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
    call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
      // Show stream in some video/canvas element.
    });
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to get local stream' ,err);
  });
});
```

Problem is: to get the remoteStream, I need to show my own stream

```
var call = peer.call('another-peers-id', stream);
```

How can I play someone else stream without having to show my own stream ?

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a bug, you just got confused how WebRTC API works. We first create a function variable named `getUserMedia` which will be mapped to native webrtc method provided by browser (for example in case the browser is Chrome then method `navigator.getUserMedia` will be assigned to this variable and rest will be null. Similarly if browser is Firefox then native method `navigator.mozGetUserMedia` is assigned to this variable and rest will be null and so on).

Once appropriate native method is assigned to the variable `getUserMedia`, we then call this method with appropriate arguments. This first argument is type of call we want to create (i.e. media constraints), e.g. audio only, audio + video and so on. The second argument is a callback in case of success (i.e. when browser successfully able to access and connect to local mic and/or camera etc.). An example of this callback function would be,

```
function(stream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    // Do something with the video here.
  };
}
```

There is a third argument for `getUserMedia` method which is optional and missing in your example code, this argument is a callback to another method which will kick-in in case getUserMedia method fails. There can be many reasons for failure, e.g. user disallowed the browser to acccess local mic or camera etc. Using this call back method you can inform user about call failure issues.

Here is full example code (Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (getUserMedia) {
  getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
  function(stream) {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      video.play();
    };
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
  }
);
} else {
  console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

If you do not want to send your own audio and/or video, then simply set it to false in media constraints variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with  getUserMedia({video: false, audio: false}... and had error as well.
Should I use  getUserMedia(false... only ?

Comment: Ah, i see you want to establish two way communication but only want to send media one way. Well, that's a standard PTT (push to talk) setup. All you need to do is to change the media IP of relevant media in caller SDP to 0.0.0.0 (e.g. if you want to to receiving video but do not send video then set media IP in video part of SDP to 0.0.0.0).

Comment: There is another alternative, which is more relevant in call hold function but can also be used here. That is, just add or update an SDP attribute at the end of SDP indicating you only want to receive media and not to send media, e.g. change "a=sendrecv" to "a=recvonly". Similarly the remote party can add / update this attribute in its response SDP, in which case it would be to "a=sendonly".

Comment: Ok. But how to do that inside peer.js ?

Comment: Well, i doubt the PeerJS API has any built-in way to access SDP but probably you have to hack its code to inject your modifications. Here is basic theory of what needs to be done.

Using the connection object, a local offer needs to be created (using native function `createOffer`), which when successful (like `getUserMedia` method) runs a callback function which generated offer as its input. There you can manipulate the `offer.sdp` before setting it as local session description.

Comment: Here is a theoretical example,

`peerConnection.createOffer(
  function(offer) {
    console.debug("The offer SDP:", offer.sdp);

    // here change / edit offer.sdp as needed
    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

    // your signaling code to communicate the offer goes here
  }
);
`

Comment: I think the correct location for this in peer.js file would be just above line 613, i.e. before the method `pc.setLocalDescription`.

Comment: Could not make it work. Maybe I can reward you if you help me to complete the task ?

Comment: In your project posted on upwork you asked to reply your question here on slack overflow, which i did, detailing exactly what needs to be done where to get the required result. I guess rest should be done via upwork so developers like me may make ends meet. ;-)

Comment: Here is my profile, https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01f73d5fe660122262

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for everyone stumbling across this like me, I managed to do it like this:

```
let call = myPeer.call(peer_id, new MediaStream(), {
            constraints: {
              offerToReceiveAudio: true,
              offerToReceiveVideo: true,
            }
          });
call.on('stream',...)
```